# Past tense of "cannot have p.p."

Tags: past-tense, modal-verbs

I will be a king.

"Will" becomes "would" in subordinate clauses of past tense verbs.

I thought I would be a king.

Then, does "can't have p.p." become "couldn't have p.p.?

For example,

Does "he can't have lied to me, he's one of honest guys" become "I thought he couldn't have lied to me, he was one of honest guys"?

Comment: "he's the one of honest guys" is wrong.  Try: He's one of the honest guys.

Comment: It's still wrong. You need **the**. It's not optional

Comment: With verbs like _thought_ and  _hoped_ it does.

Comment: (Ignoring the omitted "the"): Yup. It does. That's not much of a question, though; maybe if you add more about your concern we can get a more meaningful answer.

Comment: Native speakers often don't bother repeating the past tense verb in such contexts. To my ear, *When he saw her yesterday she **can't** have been happy* is just as good as *When he saw her yesterday she **couldn't** have been happy.* It's really just a matter of personal preference there - and as a rule, *simpler is better*.